# Calculate height of one trapezium inscrit in another

Tags: geometry

Let t be a trapezium of area a inscrit in another trapezium T of area A, where A = 2a.
[image]

B1, B2 and H, the bases and height of T are known.

Given that A = 2a, I would like to calculate h, the height of t.

How can I do this without knowing b2, the second base of t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could answer this one with the proportion theorem in Geometry.

The parallel lines in the triangle produces two equiangular triangles that are therefor similar.

$$\frac{\text{Area of small Triangle}}{\text{Area larger triangle}}=\frac{a-b_1h}{2a-b_1H}$$
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}(b_2-b_1)h}{\frac{1}{2}(B_2-B_1)H}=\frac{a-b_1h}{2a-b_1H}$$
But by the similarity of the triangles  $\frac{b_2-b_1}{B_2-B_1}=\frac{h}{H}$ so
$$\frac{h^2}{H^2}=\frac{a-b_1h}{2a-b_1H}$$
$$h^2(2a-b_1H)=(a-b_1h)(H^2)$$
$$(2a-b_1H)h^2+(b_1H^2)h-aH^2=0$$

Now you'll have to solve the quadratic equation, assuming $a$ is also known

Comment: Thanks, I'm having difficulty understanding the RHS of the very first line (a-b1h)/(2a-b1h) - where does this term come from? ... Sorry of course it the area of the trapezium - that of the triangle

Comment: Well the triangle's area is the trapezium's area minus the rectangle's area, So for example the small trapezium's area is a and the rectangle's area is B1 (or b1) times h, so the triangle's area a-b1*h. Similarly for the larger triangle. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's it, thanks.

Comment: Pleasure. I love this site, i get so many problem solving questions for my high school students - cannot believe how many can be solved by similarity :P